# Test connection of linked servers and return connected linked server(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write a script to test all linked servers and return the only one that is connected (there is for sure only one).

Here is my current script but I am stuck at that point:

```
DECLARE @retval INT
DECLARE @connected INT
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

SET @connected = 0

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name as Servers FROM sys.servers


OPEN @getid

FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
        EXEC @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @name
        SELECT @name
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getid INTO @name

END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

But using this query, the code stop at the first iteration since it can't connect to the first server of the table.
Here is the error message:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server1" returned message " Communication link failure;-10709 Connect failed (connect timeout expired)".
>       Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_testlinkedserver, Line 1
>       Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server1".

Any idea, how to pass through the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed a few things in your code... give this a shot.

- IsOff just means the connection failed.
- I added a where clause to look at Linked Servers only
- I've never seen a cursor as a variable so I removed that and the other variables I didn't need
- Used a TRY/CATCH since sys.sp_testlinkedserver raises and exception if it doesn't success.
- Return the reason why it failed
- Stored all the results into a table variable and only returned the failures

.

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)

declare @table table (IsOff int, ServerName varchar(100), TheError varchar(4000))


DECLARE getid CURSOR FOR
SELECT  name FROM sys.servers where is_linked = 1


OPEN getid

FETCH NEXT FROM getid INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    begin try
        exec sys.sp_testlinkedserver @name
    end try

    begin catch
        insert into @table
        values
        (1,@name,ERROR_MESSAGE())
    end catch

FETCH NEXT FROM getid INTO @name

END

CLOSE getid
DEALLOCATE getid

select ServerName, TheError from @table where IsOff = 1
```

Comment: Works Great. Thank you.

Here is the final code of what I need

Comment: See below for full solution

Comment: @antoinem you added `product = 'HANA' AND [catalog] = 'HP5'`. This would be unique to your environment only.

Comment: Agree. I removed it for the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code of my question:

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)

declare @table table (IsOff int, ServerName varchar(100), TheError varchar(4000))


DECLARE getid CURSOR FOR
SELECT  name FROM sys.servers 
where is_linked = 1


OPEN getid

FETCH NEXT FROM getid INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    begin try
        exec sys.sp_testlinkedserver @name
        insert into @table
        values
        (1,@name,'Server is Connected')
    end try

    begin catch
        insert into @table
        values
        (0,@name,ERROR_MESSAGE())
    end catch

FETCH NEXT FROM getid INTO @name

END

CLOSE getid
DEALLOCATE getid

select * from @table
where IsOff = 1
```