# SQL Open Query Inside TRY and CATCH Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day. I am trying to perform an `OPEN QUERY` Inside of a `TRY` and `CATCH`. I want to `TRY` to get data from a remote server and if the connection fails; I would like to perform the `CATCH`. However, the error will persist and not go into the `CATCH`.

I read that there are certain errors that `TRY` and `CATCH` wont work on. Am I doing this wrong?  Any other method of trying to find out via script whether or not a query connection has connected or failed? And if failed go and perform some other action (alert that the database didn't connect essentially)

Any help is most appreciated.

```
BEGIN try 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   Openquery([xxx-xxx\xx_xx], 'select * from xxx.dbo.xxx') 
END try 

BEGIN catch 
    SELECT 2 as STATUS 
END catch
```

The error I get when I I intentionally misspell the server or turn it off. ( If I run the OPEN QUERY by itself it works fine. I already did the sp_add linked server FYI)

```
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 33
Could not find server 'xxx-xxx\xx_xx' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

Comment: I dont get the issue - the error says the linked server doesnt exist

Comment: correct. How do I return a status that it didnt connect. It just errors out. I am trying to set a variable equal to something and pass it along in the catch method

Comment: i would do an if exists in sys.servers/then block...

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36178/linked-server-error-not-caught-by-try-catch

Comment: The link helped. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47400132/6167855

Answer (score 1):

```
if exists (Select name from sys.servers where name=yourname)
    SELECT * 
    FROM   Openquery([xxx-xxx\xx_xx], 'select * from xxx.dbo.xxx') 

else
    SELECT 2 as STATUS
```

Comment: so what you did was check the sys.servers to see if the connection is there by name... so if the connection isnt there, then it would go into the else statement. i see the work around. I like it. The question is..... if the server does lose connection then it wont show up in the query then right?

Comment: Look at the columns in sys.servers - you might be able to filter off of one of those that would change if the connection is lost - otherwise you might need a different solution - the solution above will check if the linked server exists or not

Comment: True. I turned off services to the remote server and got the good ol named pipes error. But when I ran the query (select name from sys.servers) it still showed the connection. I am trying the link someone posted above as well. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah I checked out the link too - looks like you'll find something good there

Comment: The answer by Max Vernon on that link was the  one. Thanks man.